# Prevent dialogs appearing in unattended builds

Tags: build-process, automation, build-automation

I was wondering is there is a fool-proof way to run a program on windows such that I'm **guaranteed** that **no interactive dialogs of any kind** are displayed.

I've tried the registry ErrorMode hack, calling _CrtSetReportMode(), etc., but they all have holes in them or require you to modify the program.

I need a way to run an **arbitrary** program and practically force Windows to execute them such that there is no possibility for them to open a window. It is perfectly ok for the program to crash if it attempts to open a window.

Would running the program as a service solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any other ways that might possibly work. Running as a service won't solve the problem either as the dialog will be displayed on the service's desktop, which you generally don't have access to.

Comment: What does that mean? Does the application still wait for the dialog to complete? I can accept that I'm not seeing the dialog (I can always rerun the build manually), as long as the application does not wait for the dialog.

Comment: Even when running a program on the nonvisible service desktop, it will still wait for the nonexistent user to press a nonvisible button to dismiss the dialog box. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: How meaningless. As usual, the lack of design can be seen in every corner of Windows.

Comment: Yes, as Greg mentioned, the application will still wait for a user response which is why running as a service won't solve your problem either.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library such as [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/sn/detours/) to intercept all calls to functions that might display a dialog box (this might in fact be nearly everything in `user32.dll`).